# What does "3-sigma" type of event mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "3-sigma" type of event mean? For example,

> Hurricane Sandy is a 3-sigma type of event.

Comment: So, probability 0.003, or 1 in 300.  Figuratively, very rare.  You will have to read more to see what they really mean.  Maybe a storm like this will hit New York City about once in 300 years.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-sigma_rule

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The greek letter sigma is used as a  measure (the standard deviation) of how much some series of events vary around the average. Events much bigger or smaller than the average are rarer than events close to the average

For a certain type of [statistical distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)  you can say that 1/3 of the events will be more than 1 sigma from the average, 5% more than 2 and only 0.3% more than 3 etc etc. It's only valid for things which follow this particular curve - which hurricanes probably don't - so in this case it's a bit of scientific sounding jargon to sound good in a news cast.

It's popular in the US because there was a business philosophy called 6sigma  based on the idea that your business should be 6 standard deviations better than average ( ie 1/500,000,000)

Comment: Good answer, but I think most scientists believe that most natural phenomena follow a normal distribution, at least the trends of [death and destruction from hurricanes](http://ascelibrary.org/action/showAbstract?page=57&volume=13&issue=1&journalCode=nhrefo) do, so I don't think the caveat that "hurricanes probably don't" is needed.

Comment: Hurricane strength probably isn't Gaussian because there are hard limits at the upper and lower end of the available thermal power. Damage might be Gaussian because it sums a very large number of essentially random events